# Kotlin 'until' fun creating IntRange garbage

Tags: kotlin

I was using the `until` infix fun for my loop below

```
for (x in 0 until bodies.size) bodies[x]()
```

when profiling my code with YourKit I noticed that I had a huge amount of IntRange objects (about 2k/sec).
[image]

When I switch the loop to use the `int...int` rangeTo directly it does not create any garbage.

```
for (x in 0..bodies.size-1) bodies[x]()
```

Can someone please explain the difference between these two? From what I can tell `Int.until` simply returns `this .. to`

```
public infix fun Int.until(to: Int): IntRange {
    val to_  = (to.toLong() - 1).toInt()
    if (to_ > to) throw IllegalArgumentException("The to argument value '$to' was too small.")
    return this .. to_
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version v1.0.4  the compiler optimises calls for `rangeTo` and `downTo` functions since they are the most common in `for` loops.

I think they'll optimises `until` away some time soon.

Here is the relevant issue ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9900.
Feel free to vote it up.